# Does stan do predictive posteriors?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, stan

Does stan (in particular, rstan) have built-in facilities to generate predictive posterior distributions?

It's not hard to generate the distribution from the stan fit, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There is a generated quantities section at the end that is supposed to be able to handle simulation, but the documentation (as of ver. 1.3, but ver. 2 should be out soon) does not explain in much detail how to accomplish this. You might consider asking the mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Stan User manual v2.2.0](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.2.0/stan-reference-2.2.0.pdf) (pages 361–362):

> In Stan, posterior simulations can be generated in two ways. The first
>   approach is to treat the predicted variables as parameters and then
>   define their distributions in the model block. The second approach,
>   which also works for discrete variables, is to generate replicated
>   data using random-number generators in the generated quantities block.

I usually use the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The following is not a thorough answer, but hopefully it's better than no answer. In my own applications I apply posterior predictive checks to examine model predictions for a single dependent measure which has been generated from a linear model. This is simple in JAGS, but somewhat more opaque in Stan.

```
data{
    int<lower=1> N; // no. rows
    real x[N]; // predictor
    real y[N]; // dependent variable
}
parameters{
    real alpha; // int.
    real beta; // slope
    real<lower=0> sigma_e; // resid. var.
    real y_tilde[N]; // post. pred.
}
model{
    real mu[N];
    for(i in 1:N){
        mu[i] <- alpha + beta*x[i];
    }

    y ~ normal(mu,sigma_e); //lik
    y_tilde ~ normal(mu,sigma_e);

    alpha ~ normal(0,5);
    beta ~ normal(0,5);
    sigma_e ~ cauchy(0,5);
}
generated quantities{
    real minimum;
    real maximum;
    minimum <- min(y_tilde);
    maximum <- max(y_tilde);
}
```

There must be a better way to do this, so someone please post a better answer. But the above code generates N posterior predictive distributions, one for each observation. I do this so that the a predictive distribution of extrema can be found, but if you only are interested in the posterior predictive quantity `y_tilde` you may be able to do without all of them. For large data sets the above solution is obviously too space-intensive.